# How to use -Identity <mailbox>

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

The full command I am trying to run is:

```
Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity <mailbox>
```

I interpreted that as:

```
Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity jack
```

Is that correct? Should it be jack@domain.com? Domain/jack?

I'm not getting an error but it's not doing what I think it should either.

What I'm trying to do is force a retention policy to apply for an account (it's set to run on his inbox sent and deleted items) as I don't want to wait the 7 days for it to run automatically.

Also, the credentials in using in powershell to connect are not the Jack account but the admin account. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Note that `domain/jack` is invalid and many operations require the slash be in the correct direction, which is the **backslash**, so you would have to put `domain\jack` instead.

Comment: Note that the command you are running is only one part of configuring MRM in Exchange Online. If it's not doing anything, you might have to make sure the other steps have been completed and the other parts of MRM are configured. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150558(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The -Identity parameter will work with the *mailbox alias*, which I find to be the easiest way to specify a mailbox.

You can get a list of aliases for all of your mailboxes by running simply `get-mailbox`.

In addition:

> The Identity parameter specifies the mailbox that you want to view. You can use any value that uniquely identifies the mailbox.
>   For example:
>
> - Name
> - Display name
> - Alias
> - Distinguished name (DN)
> - Canonical DN
> - `<domain name>\<account name>`
> - Email address
> - GUID
> - LegacyExchangeDN
> - SamAccountName
> - User ID or user principal name (UPN)
>
> You can't use this parameter with the *Anr*, *Database*, *MailboxPlan* or *Server* parameters.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685(v=exchg.160).aspx)

If you are definitely using an accepted value type for the -Identity parameter and it's not working, you may have another problem, such as not being connected to the right organization, server, or service, or the object type might be wrong for the command you are issuing.

I always like to run a `get-<setting>` before I run a `set-<setting>` to make sure I'm accessing the right object to make a change. Also, a `get-<object type>` to list all the objects (e.g., `get-mailbox`) and/or a `get-<object type> -Identity <identity>` helps confirm that I'm working on the right object with the right identity value.